# C++ DLL can use WMI

Tags: c++, qt, wmi

Can I use WMI in a DLL (compiled in Visual Studio...) and load that DLL in Qt?

Comment: Question is unclear to me. What do you want to do with WMI on this DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use WMI on a DLL.